# Langchain RetrievalQA: Missing some input keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, langchain, py-langchain, retrieval-augmented-generation

I have created a RetrievalQA Chain, but facing an issue. When calling the Chain, I get the following error: `ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query', 'typescript_string'}`

My code looks as follows:

```
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="intfloat/multilingual-e5-large",
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'mps'}, encode_kwargs={'device': 'mps', 'batch_size': 32})

vectorstore = FAISS.load_local("vectorstore/db_faiss_bkb", embeddings)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 1, 'score_treshold': 0.75}, search_type="similarity")
llm = build_llm("modelle/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q5_K_M.gguf")

def build_retrieval_qa(llm, prompt, vectordb):
    chain_type_kwargs={ "prompt": prompt,
                        "verbose": False
                        }
    dbqa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                        chain_type='stuff',
                                        retriever=vectordb,
                                        return_source_documents=True,
                                        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
                                        verbose=True
                                        )
    return dbqa

prompt = """
<s> [INST] You are getting a task and a User input. If there is relevant information in the context, please add this information to your answer.

### Here the Task: ###
{typescript_string}

### Here the context: ###
{context}

### Here the User Input: ###
{query}

Answer: [/INST]
"""

prompt_temp = PromptTemplate(template=prompt, input_variables=["typescript_string", "context", "query"])

dbqa1 = build_retrieval_qa(llm=llm,prompt=prompt_temp,vectordb=retriever)

question = "What is IGB?"
types = "Answer shortly!"

dbqa1({"query": question, "typescript_string": types})
```

With this code the error from above occurs in the last line here.

The weird thing is, that it is working with a LLM-Chain from Langchain without Retrieval:

```
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

llm_chain = LLMChain(
        llm=llm,
        prompt= prompt_temp,
        verbose=True,
)

test = llm_chain({"type_string": types, "input": question})
test
```

This works and I am getting a correct response.
I am using

> Langchain == 0.1.0

So is there something wrong with my PromptTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to solve the issue posted here in this discussion: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/11542#discussioncomment-8184412

Here the answer if the webpage changes:
So got it working but figured out a weird behaviour. My prompt & code looks as follows and it works:

```
rag_prompt= """
<s> [INST] Im folgenden bekommst du eine Aufgabe. Erledige diese anhand des User Inputs.
Falls im Kontext relevante Informationen enthalten sind, die deine Antwort verbessern, füge diese in deine Antwort ein. 
Wichitg ist, dass du keine zusätzlichen Informationen erfindest, sondern gegebenenfalls nur die im Kontext enthaltenen.
Die Antwort soll sich nicht wiederholen.

### Hier die Aufgabe: ###
{typescript_string}

### Hier Kontext zum User Input: ###
{{context}}

### Hier der User Input: ###
{{question}}

Antwort: [/INST]
"""

rag_prompt = rag_prompt.format(typescript_string="Schreibe die Stichpunkte in einen Volltext um.")
def set_rag_prompt():
    return PromptTemplate(template=rag_prompt, input_variables=['typescript_string', 'context', 'question'])

from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="intfloat/multilingual-e5-large",
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'mps'}, encode_kwargs={'device': 'mps', 'batch_size': 32})

vectorstore = FAISS.load_local("vectorstore/db_faiss_bkb", embeddings)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 1, 'score_treshold': 0.75}, search_type="similarity")
llm = build_llm("modelle/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q5_K_M.gguf")
qa_prompt = set_rag_prompt()
def build_retrieval_qa(llm, prompt, vectordb):
    chain_type_kwargs={ "prompt": prompt,
                        "verbose": False
                        }
    dbqa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                        chain_type='stuff',
                                        retriever=vectordb,
                                        return_source_documents=True,
                                        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
                                        verbose=True
                                        )
    return dbqa


dbqa = build_retrieval_qa(llm=llm,prompt=qa_prompt,vectordb=retriever)
dbqa({"query": "Test Query"})
```

The weird behaviour is happening in naming the Prompt input variables. It is only working if the input_variable pair is "context" and "question". Before (when it did not work), "{question}" was named "{query}" in the Prompt and when calling the RetrievalQA chain with `dbqa({"query": "Test Query"})` it gave me a "Key Error {query}". After renaming it to "question" the code runs through.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: updated it. Please check it this fits the requirements

Comment: Faced the same challenge but not been able to get it to work.

Comment: I updated my prompt template like so         prompt_template = f"{prompt_template} {query}" cause for me after following his format, I was able to get the issue of validation error resolved but the query was not being passed somehow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values of `{typescript_string}` and `{query}` have not been transferred into `template`, even `dbqa1({"query": question, "typescript_string": types})` is defined to provide values in `retrieval` only (rather than in `prompt`).

Suggest to use `RunnablePassthrough` function and giving an example with Mistral-7B model downloaded locally (actually in this code, everything is running locally).

```py
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")


from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(
    ["Harry Potter's owl is in the castle"], embedding=embeddings)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()


# from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
template = """Answer the question based on on the following context:
{context}

Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)


from langchain_community.llms import GPT4All
model = GPT4All(
    model="/home/jeff/.cache/huggingface/hub/gpt4all/mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf",
    device='gpu',
    n_threads=8)


from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda, RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)

result = chain.invoke("Where is the hedwig?")
print(result)
```

PS. The credit for this issue goes to Jerry, with whom I discussed the matter yesterday

Comment: how would you adapt this in a RetrievalQA chain? I don't really get where "typescript_string" and "query" are set in your example

Comment: `RunnablePassthrough` function is alternative of `RetrievalQA` in LangChain. This function ensures to set variables, like `query`, for **both** `prompt` and `retriever`. In your previous code, the variables got set in `retriever`, but not in `prompt`. That's why LLM complains the missing keys.

Answer (score 0):

When incorporating JSON-like examples within Python format strings, particularly in templates or prompts for language models, it's crucial to double the braces ({{ and }}) around JSON objects. This is necessary because single braces are interpreted by Python as placeholders for variable substitution. Doubling the braces escapes them, allowing the JSON format to be included directly in the string without being mistaken for a variable to be replaced. This solution ensures that any JSON-like syntax within your string is correctly interpreted as literal text rather than a variable or placeholder.
for example:

```
system_message_template = "<s>" + B_INST + B_SYS + """
                                             Use the following context to answer the questions:
                                             --------------
                                             {context}
                                             --------------
                                             Please provide the answers in JSON format.
                                             Example: Who is the Primary Borrower
                                             "Primary Borrower: ": [
                                               {{
                                                 "value": "HAPPY MAILMAN MIDTOWN LLC ",
                                                 "key_confidence": 82.62330627441406,
                                                 "val_confidence": 98.17585754394531
                                               }}
                                              ]
 
                                             If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know. Don't try to make up an answer. 
                                            """ + E_SYS+E_INST+"</s>"
```

Note:Only the context should be in single braces({}). JSON-like structures must be in double braces({{ }}).